# Derivative of fractional iteration.

Tags: functional-calculus

On wikipedia, I know it's not the best reference but still, there is [an article about fractional iterations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function). I attach the fragment I want to ask about.

How do we calculate derivative of fractional iteration? I know this formula works for natural $n$ but how does it work with fractions? I didn't find anything on internet but maybe I just dont know where to look for.

[image: pic1]

Comment: Do you mean: How do we *calculate* the derivative of fractional iteration?

Comment: Yes exactly. For instance how do we calculate $f^{\frac{1}{2}}(x)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer:

You might want to take a look at [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus)

The notation here is a bit confusing.

$f^n(x)$ is often used for the nth derivative of f (ie: $\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}$)

However here it is being used for repeated functional composition.

ie:  $f(f(f(...))) $

One could consider an operator $H$ that when applied twice to a function gave the derivative.

$H(H(f(x))) = \frac{df}{dx} = D(F(x))$

$H$ could be thought of as the fractional derivative $D^\frac{1}{2}$.

Wikipedia gives an [example of computing such an operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus#Fractional_derivative_of_a_basic_power_function)

$\frac{d^a}{dx^a} x^k = \frac{k!}{(k-a)!}x^{k-a}$

They replace the factorial with the gamma function to allow for non integer values.

I'm not sure if there's a proof of the uniqueness of such a solution.

Comment: I suppose one could consider a transform H such that $H(H(x)) = f(x)$ and consider $f^\frac{1}{2} = H$

Comment: Thats pretty much a transformation im looking to calculate derivative from. More specific im doing a research about functional iterative roots, and this is the problem im facing: 
Given a function $F$ we define $F^{\frac{1}{n}}$ as a function that composited with itself $n$ times gives $F$. I want to calculate a simple derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$ from function $F^{\frac{1}{n}}$. I know how it would look like if the degree of compostion was natural but i have no clue on how to calculate that from function that is "fractioanly coposited"

Comment: hmm.. The method might be different for every function. Given f(x) = x + b  ; 

$f^n(x) = x + nb$
so $f^\frac{1}{2}(x) = x + 0.5b$